# same file with .php and without .php without any mod_rewrite RewriteRule

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, webserver

I have installed a Apache (on ubuntu) with some vhosts.
In the www-dirs I have a file (for example) called info.php. And I can
open this file by /info.php AND /info (without the .php at the end).

There is no mod_rewrite rule in the Vhost or the dir.

And if I try a rewrite rule like:

```
RewriteRule ^info$ http://www.google.com/ [R=307,L]
```

and reopen /info (without the .php) it dosn't work.

When I change the role to

```
RewriteRule ^info.php$ http://www.google.com/ [R=307,L]
```

and reopen the /info it works.

And when I try this rule:

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ echo.php?value=$1 [L]

and open a site like /foo and print the $value I get "*echo.php*". When I try /foo/bar I get "*echo.php/bar*"

Does anyone have a tip for me?

Add:
Here are some information from the phpinfo():

```
SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/test/echo.php 
QUERY_STRING    value=echo.php
REQUEST_URI     /foo
SCRIPT_NAME     /echo.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `RewriteCond` before your `RewriteRule` that matches the base case where no rewriting should occur. Otherwise your redirected request will also be rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

The dollar sign marks the end of a string. You could use (untested):

```
RewriteRule ^info(.php)?$ http://www.google.com/ [R=307,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Being able to access files without needing to write extensions is caused by [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/content-negotiation.html#negotiation) options in Apache. To disable it, use:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

You can try turning it off and see if it works or not.

Alternatively, for your `echo.php`, you can just use:

```
RewriteRule . echo.php [L]
```

And then have `echo.php` check from `REQUEST_URI` which contains the path that is originally requested.